# Creating files on AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file, io

I'm trying to store some data in a binary file:

```
import os, pickle

o = some_object()
file = open('test', 'wb') #this causes the error
pickle.dump(o, file)
file.close()
```

I get this error: **IOError: invalid mode: wb**

It doesn't work (neither on test server or GAE itself), apparantly because it does't have the write permission.

How can I create files on Appengine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GAE is readonly, you can only store stuff in the datastore

[here is a link to the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The%5FSandbox)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. thanks for saving me time, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is you shouldn't.  I suggest you store this info in BigTable as a Blob and serve it up that way.